# Finding permutation with a condition

Tags: group-theory, permutations

Let $a$ be a permutation in $S_6$. I'm asked whether there is an $a$ so that $a^2 = (123)(456)$
I'm quite confused about where to start. I do know the $a$ must consist of $3$ elements (right?).

How do I proceed?

Comment: What do you mean by an "element" of a permutation?

Comment: @arctictern ugh.. didn't know how to call it, english is not my native language. In my mind, if a=(123) then it has 3 elements.

Comment: The full cycle structure of (123) would be (123)(4)(5)(6). You're essentially talking about non-fixed-points.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hints:

- What order can $a$ have?
- What kind of permutations have that order? (Think cycle structure.)
- Now figure out what squaring does to those permutations.

---

More complete answer.

The order of $(123)(456)$ is $3$, that is $(a^2)^3=e$, or $a^6=e$. Therefore the order of $a$ must be one of the divisors of $6$. It can't be $1$, and it can't be $2$ (since then $a^2$ would be $e$). Can it be $3$ or $6$?

If it has order $3$ then it has cycle structure either $(xyz)$ or $(xyz)(pqr)$. In the former case, the square of a $3$-cycle is another $3$-cycle, so cannot be a product of disjoint $3$-cycles. That leaves the possibility $a=(xyz)(pqr)$. Squaring yields $a^2=(xzy)(prq)=(123)(456)$. See what to do?

If it has order $6$ then $a=(\color{Blue}{q}\color{Green}{r}\color{Blue}{s}\color{Green}{t}\color{Blue}{u}\color{Green}{v})$ and $a^2=(\color{Blue}{qsu})(\color{Green}{rtv})=(123)(456)$. See what to do here?

Comment: Very impressive. Thank you!

Comment: You wrote that if a has order 3 then it could be either (xyz) or (xyz)(pqr). I understand how you negated (xyz), but why can't a be of order 3 and a= (xyz)(pqr)?

Comment: @Matam It can be. I never said it couldn't be of the form (xyz)(pqr).

Comment: Yeah, I miss-read it. So a could be of order 3 and 6?

Comment: Yes. Well, order 3 *or* order 6, not order 3 "and" order 6.

Comment: Much appreciated. Yeah, I meant or :)